# Simplenews category approval

Tags: users, emails

I've got multiple newsletter purposes: some newsletters are for publicly available content and other newsletters are for example for journalists only or retailers only.

Is it possible to have each type as a Simplenews newsletter category? It doesn't seem to be out of the box, but I'm thinking it should be possible right?

My dream scenario would be to have these newsletter categories on admin/config/services/simplenews:

- General news (open for all)
- System news (mandatory for registered users)
- Press releases (admin approval required)
- Retail news (admin approval required)

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

The long term idea is to add similar user roles for the restricted newsletter subscribers enabling restricted content, wholesale prices etc.

Comment: So you're looking to restrict newsletter category signup to specified roles?

Comment: That could be an acceptable workaround but I would prefer to allow Signups for all categories for anonymous users but require admin approval on some categories before a signup becomes a subscriber so to speak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not possible out of the box.

You'll need to implement access for them, see for example https://www.drupal.org/node/1140606 for some discussions/ideas.

In 7.x-1.x, categories are terms, in 7.x-2.x they are separate entities.

However,I doubt that simplenews, in either 7.x-1.x or 7.x-2.x fully respects whatever access you define there, but patches to improve that are welcome.

Comment: Thanks @Berdir. I'll keep you posted if we do a custom solution.